# See who moved an email and from which folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Is it possible to see who moves an email from a folder to a shared folder?

We have a shared email folder named "Work". In this folder there are e-mail items who need to be processed within an amount of time.

Sometimes, someone moves e-mail items back into this Work folder. I would like to see who moved the mail item into the folder and/or where the item came from.
Maybe with somekind of notification: %Username% moved an email with subject %Subject% from %source_folder% to "Work".

I'll guess somekind of Event should check new mail in "Work" with a recieve date older than lets say 2 hour. And with the help of the internet i can make that. 
But i can't find how to extract the information "who moved it" en "From where".

Any help or push howto extract that specific information would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8010045/2258

Comment: Hello Richard, 
Thanks for your reply. The article you send i've read before and I think will not solve my problem or I don't know how to use it properly. I don't want a message with "a mail has been moved" but a message with the information who moved it and/or from wich folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Stackoverflow link provided by Richard Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009837/vba-outlook-event-moving-email/8010045#8010045), running it on machines of all users, you'll get an event the exact moment the mail is moved. The user running it can be queried using [NameSpace.CurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869341.aspx). Putting these two together gives you the required information.

You'll probably want to gather this information in a central location for monitoring. As a suggestion, you could use the Outlook Object Model to send yourself a mail with this information. Additionally you might want to display a message informing the user that they really shouldn't be moving work back into the work folder (and management has been informed about their action). Using appropriate (nice and friendly) wording of course.

Comment: Hello Paul-Jan, I've used the link that Richard send and put it al together in ThisOutlookSession. At the moment I get a message when a mail has moved into "work" older than 3 hours. 
If I understand your comments correctly I have to install this script on every users client (about 150 users) to get the CurrentUser? I cannot get this information only by running this script on my computer? If that's the case your e-mail option is very nice method wich I should look into, butt I'm still hoping I do not have to install this on everyone's outlook.

Comment: Ok. Now i get an e-mail if an mail item is added to the "work" folder wich is revcieved over 3 hours ago. But how do I get the name of who put it in there? with the current user I'll just get a name who has this script active right? The scripts starts at the moment an mail item was placed into the folder. So Everyone is the current user.